# Ionic 3 File Download using External Sharepoint File URL

Tags: angular, sharepoint, ionic3, spfx

I am created project Ionic with Sharepoint,

I have a stored pdf, xls, doc, etc.. file in list,
I have a actual path of a file URL,
I am create documents Gallery in my app with download option,
when i'm click download icon i have to download a that particular document.

I have tried

**file trasfer plugin**

i can't achieve pls help me to solve this problem.

here my tried code.

file trasfer way:-

```
 this.download("sample","https://abcd.sharepoint.com/samplesite/Shared Documents/sample.pdf");

 download(fileName: string, filePath: any) {
        const url= encodeURI(filePath);
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();      
        fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.externalRootDirectory + fileName, true).then((entry) => {
          //show toast message as success    
        }, (error) => {
          //show toast message as error        
        });
    }
```

pls give some idea to download a file. Is there any other way is available to download a file using url in ionic3?

Comment: Finally i got an answer my self. working pdf, excel file has download success.

Comment: But there is a problem while downloading word file. It shows allways file has been corrupted. I have to find other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file-transfer
```

function

```
const url = 'https://abcd.sharepoint.com/samplesite/Shared Documents/sample.pdf';
  fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'sample.pdf').then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
  }, (error) => {
    // handle error
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  this.file.dataDirectory once i use it this path i can't view the file in my mobile.

Comment: otherwise, Use the file path  this.file.externalRootDirectory i find the file. But once i am open it. It shows "The file appears to be corrupted" popup appeared